# Cast to ObjectId error when doing findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection `jobs` that references a collection `users` via a jobOwner field and i'm using `Mongoose` as my `ORM`.

When i try `Job.findOneAndUpdate({jobOwner:userId})`

I get the error `"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "user" at path "jobOwner""`

`userId` is a string with the appropriate `_id` of the user. I've tried converting it to an `objectId` by doing   `userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)` and I still get the same error.

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Based on the error message, it sure sounds like `userId` contains `"user"`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your id value equals "user" instead of a valid object id that it is expecting. Log it to console and check. You probably have a mistake somewhere.